Is there a typo in the new Conjure Woodland beings?
The 4th level Druid and Ranger spell Conjure Woodland Beings has been significantly altered in the 2024 rules. Instead of calling minions to fight for you and mess up the action economy balance, it now creates an Emanation that deals damage, much in the way Spirit Guardians does.
What puzzles me is the Using a Higher-Level Spell Slot line it has. It says:

Using a Higher-Level Spell Slot. The damage increases by 1d8 for each spell slot level above 5.

For ALL other spells in the PHB (unless I missed some) that increase damage when cast at a higher level slot, the level you need to go above is the level of the spell itself (here, 4th level). But here it is one level higher than that, this only starts for slot levels above 5, meaning if you cast it at level 5 instead of 4, you get no damage increase. There is a one level damage increase gap.
I think this must be a typo. Does anyone know if this already has been corrected in errata (or if it maybe, surprisingly, is not a typo)?

It could be a typo, but there were some (legacy) spells that scale with slots of two level above the spell level: for example, Elemental Weapon. Flame Blade scales every two slots.

@Eddymage true, but scaling every two levels seems intentional, whereas scaling every level except for one seems like an odd choice or mistake to me.

@Eddymage I dug around myself a bit now, and I think it is as typo here. See the answer. Elemental weapon still has a similar behaviour, but is differently templated, it does not say the damage increases with spell level, it explains specifically for which spell levels what damage is caused. Flame blade as a level 2 spell now works by adding 1d6 for each level above 2, like all the other linear scaling ones.

@DarioSeidl Elemental weapon starts to scale 2 level slots before its level spell (yes, I use present tense and not past tense since for me 2024 rules do not exists... :-D)

Similar question about strangely-worded 2014 spiritual weapon: How does the damage for Spiritual Weapon work when cast at a higher level?

It is a typo
While it has not been officially anounced yet in an erratum, Wizards have already changed the text for the feature in the free online version of the 2024 Conjure Woodland Beings
The text there now reads

Using a Higher-Level Spell Slot. The damage increases by 1d8 for each spell slot level above 4.

See also this discussion about some other similar unofficial errata.

Nice Catch!

The Free Rules 2024 say:

Using a Higher-Level Spell Slot. The damage increases by 1d8 for each spell slot level above 4.

So apparently, this has already been errataed.
